# Why I can't build my custom component with Oracle JET?

Tags: oracle, oracle-jet

I have created a custom component with ojet, but when I have tried to build it, I got an error: "Error: Invalid platform component"
How have i do it:

1. I have used the Oracle JET version: 5.2.0
2. I have created a new web application (proba3): "ojet create proba3 --template=navdrawer:web"
3. I'v got: "Your app is ready! Change to your new app directory 'proba3' and try 'ojet build' and 'ojet serve'"
4. "cd proba3"
5. " ojet serve"
6. The web page shows up in the browser as I expected.
7. I have created a new component (zizi-table): "ojet create component zizi-table"
8. I'v got: "Add component zizi-table finished."
9. I have have tried to build the new component: "ojet build component zizi-table"
10. I'v got: "Error: Invalid platform component"
    What is the problem?
    Any suggestions?
    Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I changed version 6.1.0, and this issue has ceased. This version works well.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to tell us the answer, even though you had no obligation to. This might help future readers.